# Rails 3 Controller do not render page

Tags: rake, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is it possible in rails 3 to have a link pointing to a controller action, but not render anything?
Let's say I just want to call a couple rake tasks. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

You can render nothing by using:

```
render :nothing => true
```

At the end of your action in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Call the method and add at the end of it a redirect_to or render to a site you want to view.
Don't forget to add this to your routes.
You can also use flash messages to show to the user that something happend :)